# How to remove last element of arraylist

Tags: java, android

I am trying to remove the last element of `arraylist` after every 10 minutes.
I am using this code to do that:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
               array.remove(array.size() -1);   //array is my ArrayList object

            }
        });
    }
};

timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 600000); //execute in every 10 minutes
```

But it is giving `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.Can anyone solve this problem.

Comment: Does your array have any elements?

Comment: @MuratK. yes it contains around 5-6 elements

Comment: Does it have it from the beginning?

Comment: [It is the same situation...](http://ideone.com/AjRkhz) solution is obvious

Comment: This can lead to memoty leaks, use WeakReference wrapper

Comment: The Exception doesn't gave you the index receive in the message ? I guess this will say `-1`. This should clearly be in a condition... Here is the message you should have received `Exception in thread "XXX" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` **-1**

Answer (score 4):

You are getting IndexOutOfBounds because you are trying to remove an item that isn't there, so you should perform a check on your removal to stop the removal if there is nothing there:

```
if(array.size() > 0){
    array.remove(array.size() -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty array as @TheAndroidDev said.
What about to use Rx, something like this:

```
Observable.from(array)
            .interval(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .map(i -> array.size() > 0 ? array.remove(array.size() - 1) : null)
            .take(array.size())
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                // Do something with the integer or type you use
            });
```

Comment: Careful that your are using an API not supported on a large scall of android devices. This is usable since Android 5 I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //check if its null or not when debugging
      if(array!=null){
        //Log something thats it is not null at this point
         if(array.size()>0){
               array.remove(array.size() -1);
           }
         else{ 
             //Log the array is empty 
           }
       }
```